# How do I inspect the in-memory representation of OCaml values?

Tags: memory, ocaml

Is there any way to inspect the in-memory representation of OCaml values *in OCaml*, without using something like gdb? Ideally, the output would give me either hex bytes or binary bits, similar to what you can get via gdb.

The [Obj module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Obj.html) looks promising, and [Real World OCaml has a section about it](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/runtime-memory-layout.html), but does it offer a single way to get in-memory representation, without having to know how every OCaml value is laid out in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched the net and I found an OCaml package named "inspect" that seems to do something like what you want. Here's what it shows for the values `true` and `[1; 2; 3]`:

```
# Sexpr.dump true;;
(DUMP 1)- : unit = ()
# Sexpr.dump [1;2;3];;
(DUMP
   (BLK/0
      :TAG 0
      :VALUES
      1
      (BLK/1 :TAG 0 :VALUES 2 (BLK/2 :TAG 0 :VALUES 3 0))))- : unit = ()
```

It's available as an opam package named "inspect". The Github page for the package repository is https://github.com/krohrer/caml-inspect.

The output won't make sense without some familiarity with the layout of OCaml values. That's unavoidable I think. There is information on the Github page and in the OCaml manual.

Comment: Interesting, this isn't what I expected but looks good enough for me, thanks!